# Which value should be used for SP for booting process?

Tags: assembly, x86, boot, bootloader

The bootstrap sequence in the BIOS will load the first valid MBR that it finds into the computer's physical memory at address 0x7C00.

Which value should be used for SP for booting process?

```
org 7c00h      ; set location counter.
mov ax, XXX    ; What is XXX?
mov sp, ax
; Now PUSH an POP are safe
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any value of `SS:SP` such that there's enough stack space for your code **AND** interrupt service routines is OK.

And, of course, your stack shouldn't collide with any of your code or other data or run into ROM or a memory-mapped device address range.

The BIOS does not guarantee what `SS:SP` your boot sector will receive. So, changing only `SP` isn't right.

You could for example do this (if there isn't any code or data of yours at this location):

```
...
mov ax, 0
mov ss, ax
mov sp, ax
...
```

This will set `SS:SP` to 0:0. Don't panic yet. The next push will first decrement `SP` from 0 to 0xFFFE and write to 0:0xFFFE, not to 0:0.

This will give you 0x10000 - (0x7c00 + 0x200) = 33280 bytes of space between the end of your boot sector and the maximum stack pointer address. That's plenty of stack space.

Also note that when changing both `SS` and `SP`, you either have to do that with interrupts disabled or first change `SS` and then change `SP` in the immediately following instruction (like shown above).

Alternatively you could use the `LSS SP, ...` instruction, but it takes as an argument an address of a far address, meaning your new `SS:SP` value would first need to be somewhere in the memory.

Yet another way to change `SS` and `SP` is to use `PUSH` and `RETF`.

Answer (score 4):

0000:0500 to 0007:FFFF is guaranteed free for use. Proper initialization looks like this:

```
org 0x0600
...

cli
xor ax, ax
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
mov ss, ax
mov sp, 0x7C00

; relocate itself
mov si, sp
mov di, 0x0600
mov cx, 256
rep movsw

; make sure we'are at 0000:0600+x
jmp 0:.reloc
.reloc:
push 2
popf    ; flags with all off
```

I use 7C00, stack goes downward and code goes upward. You may replace 7C00 with any valid range as mentioned, just make sure not overwrite your own code/data.

Btw, most MBR would relocate itself to 0000:0600 by tradition, and chain-load VBR into 7C00.

Also note the jmp .reloc, some buggy BIOS start MBR with 07C0:0000, so a jmp there make sure CS=0

Comment: I wouldn't say it was buggy BIOSes. Back in the day IBM didn't explicitly state which segment:offset pair the BIOS would use to jump to your code just that it would be loaded at 0x7c00. Even by the mid 80s MS-DOS didn't make assumptions. One of the El Torito specs years later mentioned 0x07c0:0x0000 specifically. In some environments when booting from CD it used 0x07c0:0x0000 and if it was Floppy/Hard drive it used 0x0000:0x7c00.

Comment: @MichaelPetch The boot sector on my mid-80s MS-DOS 2.11 disk ssumes CS = 0. So yah, I'd call it a BIOS bug. Also the El Torito spec doesn't quite say that CS:IP should be 07c0:0000. It just says that the default load segment is 07c0.

Comment: @RossRidge : I don't recall the exact version, or whether is was PC-DOS or MS-DOS but eventually the bootloaders were relocated out of 0x7c00 and place in lower memory and then a FAR JMP to 0:offset was done (where DS/ES were set accordingly). I know that earlier in the 80s that the bootloaders made assumptions. As for the El Torito specification, I'm not saying how I interpreted it but how many other did at the time. Interestingly enough Bochs(I can't recall if it was 2.6.4 or earlier) actually used 0x0:0x7c00 for Floppies/HD and 0x7c0:0 for CDs. And at the time they too brought up El Torito

Comment: Since the 80s it has been a pretty easy rule. If you want to run on a wide variety of hardware, make no assumptions - except for the contents of_DL_ , although some BIOS manufacturers screwed up the value in _DL_ as well.

Comment: @MichaelPetch That would be an MBR bootsector that does the relocation. Floppy (and volume) bootsectors don't do that. My 2.11 floppy stores CS:7c0b in 0000:0078, so Microsoft bootsectors didn't become safe from this bug until later than the mid-80s. I also really doubt Microsoft intentionally changed their code not to assume CS = 0, it looks more like they optimized the code and in the process happened to get rid of the assumption. Before they did that, it wouldn't have been necessary. Any such buggy BIOS would've made it to market because it wouldn't be able to boot MS-DOS from a floppy.

Comment: @RossRidge At the time there were discussion on Compuserve over this issue and the other one being the old 8088 SS:SP update bug.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I've rolled back a number of his edits. He likes to make a bunch of useless changes, basically changing the wording of a post that has nothing wrong with it. A lot of the edits subtly changed the meaning or dropped information so I rolled back those. I think I rolled back that edit because he added "I'm developing an operating system" out of nowhere.

Comment: It was a difference between IBM PC DOS 1.1 and 2.0. IBM-PC DOS 1.0 made no assumptions Version 2.0 had a fix for both the 8088 bug and also set the segment registers up front to 0. I mispoke when I said it relocate. It boot strapped additional code by loading and jumping to 0x70:0x0. I really wish that I had copies of some of those old Compuserve forums!